# How to use Unity Facebook SDK without Cocoapods/Maven

Tags: facebook, maven, unity-game-engine, cocoapods

What I am trying to achieve is to use Unitys Facebook SDK (version 7.1.9.2) without Cocoapods/Maven. The last version which used Cocoapods/Maven was 7.1.6.1. Thanks for your help before hand!

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question via examples or snippets from your work?

Comment: Unity Facebook SDK uses Cocoapods/Maven to download dependencies during build. So I would want to add these dependencies by hand before build